# Generate PDF of page using alternate/print stylesheet

Tags: php, pdf, stylesheet, alternate

I want to generate a PDF of a webpage but apply an alternate, print-type stylesheet to it instead of the styles it uses now. Say, for example, I have a button on http://eorailway.co.uk to generate a PDF of the same page (which is run and administered by me, so therefore I can include any PHP/JS necessary to each page) but I want to apply alternate styling to it before generating the PDF.

At the moment I am using the dompdf PHP library to generate the PDF using the normal/default stylesheet, but cannot for the life of me think how to apply the alternate stylesheet to the page when clicking the "Generate PDF" button.

Any advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the site is under control, you could dynamically decide which stylesheets to include based on a query string parameter. i.e. http://example.com/page.php?stylesheet=print would have your template output only the alternate stylesheet, and your PDF library would fetch that page to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making an alternate page with the "print" stylesheet applied and point to it using the print meta tag. (e.g. `<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="<? ECHO $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?print'; ?>"">` )

Then have PHP determine the stylesheet to use based on the presence of that GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOMXML stuff in php to apply a specific XSLT file to some XML:

```
 $stylsheet = "Example.xsl";
 $xsldoc = domxml_xslt_stylesheet_file($stylsheet);
 $htmldoc = $xsldoc->process($xmldoc);
 $results_page = $xsldoc->result_dump_mem($htmldoc);
```

That's something I did in php4, might be an easier way in 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the 0.6.0 release of DOMPDF you can specify the stylesheet to use by modifying the DOMPDF_DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE configuration constant.

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/browse/trunk/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php?r=336#234